# How combine data from several responses in Scala Play2?

Tags: scala, collections, playframework, future

I need do some requests to different URLs, get data from their responses and put this info in one list, but i have some misunderstanding in this theme.
1) for one request i do

```
def doRequest: Future[WSResponse] = {
client
  .url("MY_URL")
  .withRequestTimeout(5000)
  .get()}
```

Then I parse json in response to List of my objects:

```
def list: Future[List[FoobarEntry]] = {
doRequest.map {
  response => {
    val json = response.json \ "foobar"
      json.validate[List[FoobarEntry]] match {
      case js:JsSuccess[List[FoobarEntry]]=>
        js.get
      case e:JsError => Logger.error(JsError.toFlatJson(e).toString()); List()
    }
  }
}}
```

I think that for several url i should write some look like

```
def doRequests: List[Future[WSResponse]] = {
List(client
     .url("URL_1")
     .withRequestTimeout(5000)
     .get(),
     client
     .url("URL_2")
     .withRequestTimeout(5000)
     .get())}
```

But how parse this list of Future[WSResponse] like my `def list: Future[List[FoobarEntry]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you put the future responses inside of a list, you will have to map each future response with the parsing logic that turns it into a `FoobarEntry`. Like so:

```
val responseFutures: List[Future[WSResponse]] = ???
val foobarFutures: List[Future[FoobarEntry]] = 
  responseFutures.map(future => future.map(response => parse(response)))
```

Now you have a list of future parsed responses, but to do something when all of them has arrived you will need to sequence that list:

```
val futureFoobars = Future.sequence(foobarFutures)
```

So, sequence helps you to get from `C[Future[A]]` to `Future[C[A]]`

Answer (score 0):

Use for-comprehensions.

```
val request1 = client.url("URL_1").withRequestTimeout(5000).get()   
val request2 = client.url("URL_2").withRequestTimeout(5000).get() 
val result: Future[List[FoobarEntry]] = for {
   res1: WSResponse <- request1
   res2: WSResponse <- request2
} yield List(res1, res2).map(parse).flatten

def parse(response: WSResponse): List[FoobarEntry] = {
   val json = response.json \ "foobar"
   json.validate[List[FoobarEntry]] match {
      case js:JsSuccess[List[FoobarEntry]]=>
        js.get
      case e:JsError => Logger.error(JsError.toFlatJson(e).toString()) 
        List()
    }
```